# shape of membrane on circular frame with pressure difference

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

This is a problem I thought about recently, but I have no idea how to go about it: Consider a membrane evenly stretched across a round frame. What shape does this membrane take, when you have different air pressures on each side of the membrane?

Basically we have a constant force in normal direction for every small piece of the same area.

Comment: See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268398/26969) and associated answer / references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equation describing membranes separating two fluids with a pressure differential is the [Young-Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) first considered in the early 1800s. In modern geometric language the equation states that the [mean curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) of the membrane is proportional to the pressure differential.

In the case of the constant pressure differential and a circular boundary, just as the case of the meniscus in capillary surfaces, the solution is a portion of the round sphere. The radius of the sphere depends on the elasticity constant of the membrane and the pressure differential.

---

For general membranes (idealized to 2D sheet):

Suppose the configuration "at rest" is that of a unit disc $D = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: |x| \leq 1\}$. The deformation map is $$\Phi: D \to \mathbb{R}^3$$ with the condition $\Phi |_{\partial D}$ is the expected embedding of the unit circle into the $x_1-x_2$ plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The local elastic energy density is (under isotropic assumption)
$$ e[\Phi] = f(|\nabla \Phi|^2, |\partial_1 \Phi \wedge \partial_2 \Phi|^2)$$
where the function $f$ models the material properties of the membrane

The case where $f(a,b) = \sqrt{b}$ is the soap-film model (minimizing area under constraint). By changing the function $f$ you get different models of elastic membranes.

Once you have specified a function $f$, the situation you are interested in is described by thinking in terms of calculus of variations:

1. Let $E[\Phi] = \int_D e[\Phi]~\mathrm{d}A$ be the total energy. We take its $L^2$ gradient $\nabla_\Phi E$ by defining it as the function satisfying 
   $$ \int_D (\nabla_\Phi E)\psi ~\mathrm{d}A = \delta E[\Phi][\psi] $$
   for every $\psi:D\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that vanishes on the boundary. Here $\delta E$ is the variation of $E$.
2. The pressure gives force per unit area; but the area is the *stretched* area. So the force density when translated into the parametrisation by the rest state is in fact $p(\Phi) |\partial_1\Phi \wedge \partial_2\Phi|$, the pressure times the area density.
3. Force balance requires then 
   $$ p | \partial_1\Phi \wedge \partial_2\Phi| = \nabla_\phi E $$
   (basically the Euler-Lagrange equation with constraint); I removed the dependence of the pressure $p$ on position $\Phi$ since you've stated that we are facing a constant pressure differential. This equation is in general a nonlinear system of elliptic partial differential equations. The precise form of this equation depends, again, on the function $f$ that you choose.

In general probably this system of equations cannot be solved explicitly.

Comment: This seems to be a good approach too, thank you! However if I do understand this correctly it completely ignores the fact that the given membrane is not isometric to a sphere. As far as I understand the Young-Laplace equation only considers surface tension. Considering the tension within the membrane just due to it's shape would be a different problem again, right?

Comment: @flawr: what do you mean by "tension just due to its shape"? Surface tension assumes the membrane is an isotropic elastic membrane: that if you stretch it in any direction it generates a restorative force. Think of a spring but that you can stretch in multiple directions at once. So certainly it is a tension due to the shape! If you mean something else then it is up to you to specify _exactly_ how you expect the tension to vary.

Comment: That is of course one of the problems, I do not have any idea how this is modelled. The membrane is should of course be "isotropic elastic" but I think there is a difference when you look at e.g. a piece of thin rubber sheet and a soap film (I hope you understand what I mean): The forces in the soap film are only dictated by the curvature, while the rubber sheet also always wants to take a shape that is isometric to the plane.

Comment: @flawr: ah, I see what you are aiming at. I updated the post with some basics of nonlinear elasticity. Note that basically the same thing works also for deformations of elastic solids (though $f$ can depend on more things in  3D), and the civil and mechanical engineering literature has quite some things to say about specific models.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, this was way more than I ever hoped to learn here, that is exactly what I imagined! Thank you soo much!=)

Answer (score 1):

This is classic  minimal area soap film surface , it is assumed that the property of surface tension does not change with pressure, or that that the membrane is very thin.

Normal curvature $k_n$ is constant everywhere and is given by mathematical treatment as Constant Mean Curvature  (CMC) surfaces.

For a circular boundary film a spherical bubble grows in proportion to the  pressure ( force per unit area). It is given in physics also under *surface tension*.

$$ p = 2 T k_n  = 2 T /R $$

A book by Cyril Isenberg ( Science of Soap films) is insightful.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am not really sure, but i think the equation that describes this situation is just $\Delta f(x,y)=k$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $k$ is the constant pressure. For a circular membrane the solution would be a simple paraboloid.

Comment: How did you end up with this equation? I do not quite see the relation to the pressure, but it seems to be a promising approach.

Comment: This is the famous Poisson equation, there will b many references online. You can check this, for example: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/tulink/FEM14/Ch1_ElmanSyvesterWathen_Ox05.pdf

Comment: Oh right thanks. Let us consider the 1D case: Then you would obviously get a circle segment and to my knowledge this would not be the result of a Poisson equation, right?

Comment: Why do you say it is a circle segment? It will be a parabola if we are solving the Poisson equation, corresponding to "uniform load". On the other hand, maybe you wish to consider a cable hanging by its own weight, in which case you will have a catenary. Check here: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-hanging-chain-form-a-catenary-shape-rather-than-a-parabola

Comment: I was refering to the original problem: If you have a 1D membrane (a "rope" between two attachment points) and a pressure difference the membrane would take the shape of a circle segment but this was just to show that in 1D the poisson equation might not be the right model. What I think the "problem" is, is that the poisson equation only takes the force (of the pressure) in account that goes in $z$-direction, while in "reality" the force would act perpendicular to the surface, so I think your approach would just work if the membrane is nearly flat, right?

Comment: I notice that my problem is probably that I do not know how to model a membrane that allows some stretching (e.g. toy balloon). Thinking about that: This is probably quite a nontrivial problem. Thank you very much for your input so far!